# Angular6 datepicker ng change

Tags: angular6

I am using angular6 and creating one user form and using datepicker for  DOB. The DOB field is filled from server side and my problem is if I click the DOB field the date is cleared and datepicker is not open on first click.
How could I solve this problem..

Please help me to solve .

Comment: which datepicker are you using for picking DOB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`(change)="Datechange(event)"`

event to get it